# Как сделать пунктирную линию с изгибом?

Tags: html

Не могу понять как сделать такую линию проведенную с одного блока к другому
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте `SVG`

Comment: png, svg, canvas .. в чем вопрос?

Comment: любые варианты, я собрал костыль, но это не то, хочу узнать как с этой  задачей справляются другие

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего вам стоит это сделать SVG но если это  сложно реализуйте через  PNG на крайный случай
если круг строго ровно закруглен от одного края  к другому можно сделать блок задать ему

```
border-radius: 
border: 1px dashed #000;
```

> Может это вам поможет если нет то думаю SVG это то  что вы ищите

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]